# How to save Data During Routing in angular2

Tags: angular, routes

I have Two Routing in angular2 project:

The first is content list of items I show from Json when press Button,
The second is empty for testing only

**Issue is when the press in routing the data show  items  and transport to the two route and comeback to the first the data is remove from the route one**

can any one help me to save action in my route one ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import params to URL with :

```
 this.router.navigate(['/example'],{queryParams:{key1:this.key2,key2:this.key2}})
```

and To check if parmas is found and get value :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.key1  = params['key1'];
  this.key2 = params['key2'];
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be the issue is ngOnInit will be called only once during router transition. You might be forming the array in ngOnInit.  Try to subscribe for Router events inside ngOnInit which will be called while user navigates backs.

```
ngOnInit(){ 
    this.router.events.subscribe( (event: RouterEvent) => console.log(event));
}
```